# Jquery Data Attribute - Ordering & Removing Duplicates

Tags: jquery

I have a number of chat messages that contain a PID which is there row in a database table like shown below:

[image]

I need to do the following:

- Order from lowest to highest number keeping all with no number (empty ones) at the bottom.
- Remove any duplicates

I quite unsure how to do this. I have considered:

```
sort(function(a, b) {
```

or

putting them into an array, sorting the array, deleting them and then appending the sorted array.

```
.each(function () {
```

any advise would be great.

thx

Comment: What problem did you have in using `sort` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript shouldn't be used for cleaning markup, the best solution is preventing generation of duplicate elements, however if you have to do this, you can use the `sort` method as the following:

```
$('div').sort(function (a, b) {
   return + a.getAttribute('data-pid') > + b.getAttribute('data-pid');
}).appendTo('#somewhere')
  .filter(function() {
      var id = this.getAttribute('data-pid');
      // return the element if the previous sibling has the same PID
      return $(this).prev('[data-pid="'+id+'"]').length;
  }).remove();
```

Comment: Thankyou very much... I need to read on appendTo() but I assume this will overwrite any content there... great appreciated...